# How can I stop JavaFX Parent Node getting click after drag between children

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a situation where I have a container node (HBox) and two child nodes in JavaFX.  When I drag from the left child nodes in to the right, I get lots of drag events to the left node, and finally at the end when I release the mouse over the right node, I get a click event in the parent.  Below is some code to replicate this situation.

What I want to know is: how do I stop the parent receiving this click event?  I've tried all sorts of event filters and event handlers on the left and right nodes that consume the events, but I just can't seem to find the right one(s) to prevent the click event being sent to the parent.  Any ideas?

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestDrag extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        String leftHead = "Start dragging from me\n";
        String dragStarted = "Drag begun; staying simple\n";
        Label left = new Label(leftHead);

        left.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            left.setText(leftHead + dragStarted);
            e.consume();
        });

        left.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            left.setText(leftHead + dragStarted + "Mouse dragged to: " + e.getSceneX() + ", " + e.getSceneY());
            e.consume();
        });

        left.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            left.setText(leftHead + "Mouse released\n");
            e.consume();
        });

        String rightHead = "Drag on to me\n";
        Label right = new Label(rightHead);
        right.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            right.setText(rightHead + "Clicked me!\n");
        });

        left.setPrefSize(400, 300);
        left.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE, null, null)));
        right.setPrefSize(400, 300);
        right.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTPINK, null, null)));

        HBox hbox = new HBox(left, right);
        hbox.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            right.setText(rightHead + "Clicked the underlying HBox at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n");
        });


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: curious: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to stop that click from being generated.  It's a synthetic click generated by JavaFX (not by OS).  In my real code, the HBox does have a visible portion and clicking it has an effect.  I want to be able to drag between the children without triggering this click handler in the parent.

Comment: hmm ... that looks strange: a click shouldn't be fired at all if the mouse had been moved/dragged after the pressed, should it?

Comment: unexpected but documented for mouse clicked: Note that even long drags can generate click event (it is delivered to the top-most node on which the mouse was both pressed and released). Hmm ... then back to my first comment :-) Why do you want to watch for a clicked on the parent? why not use a pressed/released in the bubbling phase and not do anything if it is consumed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't prevent the event from happening per-se, but [`isStillSincePressed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#isStillSincePress--) (in `MouseEvent`) can be used in the parent (the `HBox` in this example) to distinguish between a click and a drag.

Comment: I've added that into my HBox click handler, and it does seem to do the job - I ignore clicks where isStillSincePressed is false and I seem to get the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 0):

My second reaction (as commented) was: how strange. My expectation for a clicked is Swing-based (probably Win-based also, faintly seem to remember the long past VB times): a clicked is received when both pressed/released were on the same component at the same location.

FX semantics are different as it turns out after actually reading the doc of MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED:

```
/**
 * This event occurs when mouse button has been clicked (pressed and
 * released on the same node). This event provides a button-like behavior
 * to any node. Note that even long drags can generate click event (it 
 * is delivered to the top-most node on which the mouse was both
 * pressed and released).
 */
```

So the short answer to your question is: you can't prevent the clicked on the parent. Depending on what exactly you need to achieve, there are options of how to cope with the clicked:

- don't use it at all, use a pressed/released
- implement your own at-same-location semantics: listen to the pressed in the capturing phase, store the location, compare locations in clicked and only trigger the reaction if same/near